# How to test React own component library without running project

Tags: reactjs, testing, jestjs, storybook

I am creating a component library and now I would like to test my components with something like Jest.
I would like my tests to be inside my library project meaning I don't have any access to a running react environment which makes the thing harder (at least to me).

I can't make it work, I always end up having this error "Cannot use import statement outside a module", I have mainly tried with jest with a combination of those packages: @testing-library/react, jsdom, jest-environment-jsdom, jest, @babel/preset-react and even @storybook/testing-library because my project run a storybook by I did not dig a lot into that direction as I said I mainly tried with jest.

Here is a short version of my environment:

```js
// src/components/MyComponent.tsx
import React from 'react'

export default function MyComponent() {
  return (
    <div>Hello, World!</div>
  )
}
```

```js
// src/__tests__/MyComponent.test.js
import React from "react";
import { render } from "@testing-library/react";
import MyComponent from "./components/MyComponent";

test("renders MyComponent correctly", () => {
  const { getByText } = render(<MyComponent />);
  expect(getByText("Hello, World!")).toBeInTheDocument();
});
```

```js
module.exports = {
  testEnvironment: "jsdom"
};
```

package.json (became a bit messy with all those testing packages)

```json
"peerDependencies": {
  "react": "^18.2.0",
  "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
  "react-transition-group": "4.4.5"
},
"devDependencies": {
  "@storybook/addon-essentials": "^7.5.3",
  "@storybook/addon-interactions": "^7.5.3",
  "@storybook/addon-links": "^7.5.3",
  "@storybook/addon-onboarding": "^1.0.8",
  "@storybook/blocks": "^7.5.3",
  "@storybook/react": "^7.5.3",
  "@storybook/react-vite": "^7.5.3",
  "@storybook/testing-library": "^0.2.2",
  "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^6.1.5",
  "@testing-library/react": "^14.1.2",
  "jest": "^29.7.0",
  "jest-environment-jsdom": "^29.7.0",
  "jsdom": "^23.0.1",
  "react": "^18.2.0",
  "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
  "sass": "^1.69.5",
  "storybook": "^7.5.3",
  "typescript": "^5.2.2"
}
```

I also tried to use a jest setup file but it ended up the same.

Any ideas on how to setup simple tests without any running project?
Thank you !

Comment: I don't really have a direct answer for you. But my first thought is to look at what other component libraries do. For example, [Material UI](https://mui.com/material-ui/) has a whole [test directory](https://github.com/mui/material-ui/tree/next/test), including a README that explains how to run and write tests. This might be a good place to start, including digging into their source code to understand how they have things set up.

Answer (score 0):

Testing React components or UI in general proves to be a bit more complicated than testing backend code. Try to keep it simple and use whatever the underlying framework has to offer.

For instance, With modern Node.js you can create a testing ground and render the components you want to test. Then, using an e2e tool such as cypress or playwright you can test your library as elaborately as you wish.